# Laravel relationships empty, wrong defined?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

After a little break I wanted to continue my own project. However, I am now sitting here since two hours and don't know what I am doing wrong or where my error is.

So, I have users who can create products, comment and like the comments. 
However, when I want to retrieve all products or comments the user has posted or all comments the user has liked, I always get the hasMany relationship without content (I called `$user->products()` within the dashboard blade which gets called by the `UserController`):

```
    Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany {#662 ▼
      #foreignKey: "products.user_id"
      #localKey: "id"
      #query: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder {#656 ▶}
      #parent: App\User {#654 ▶}
      #related: App\Product {#663 ▼
        #with: array:1 [▶]
        #connection: "mysql"
        #table: null
        #primaryKey: "id"
        #keyType: "int"
        +incrementing: true
        #withCount: []
        #perPage: 15
        +exists: false
        +wasRecentlyCreated: false
        #attributes: []
        #original: []
        #changes: []
        #casts: []
        #dates: []
        #dateFormat: null
        #appends: []
        #dispatchesEvents: []
        #observables: []
        #relations: []
        #touches: []
        +timestamps: true
        #hidden: []
        #visible: []
        #fillable: []
        #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      }
}
```

Can anyone tell me where I made a mistake?

User model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use HasRoles;
    use HasSettingsField;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the products record associated with the user.
     */
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }

    /**
     * Get the comments record associated with the user.
     */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }

    /**
     * Get the comment likes record associated with the user.
     */
    public function commentlikes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\CommentLike');
    }
}
```

Product model:

```
    class Product extends Model
    {

    /**
     * The relationships that should always be loaded.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $with = ['comments'];

    /**
     * Get the user that owns the product.
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Comment model:

```
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show(User $user)
{
    return view('pages.userDashboard')->with([
        'user' => $user
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think access it like a property will do. Do not call it like a method, if you do it's going to call the method.

```php
$user->products;

$user->comments;
```